# Monitor a remote FTP server with VB.net

Tags: vb.net, sockets, ftp, timeout

I am trying to create a simple monitor for a remote FTP server with this code
(built with the great help from Martin Prikryl)

```
    Private Function TestFTP(ByVal target As String, ByVal time As Integer) As Object
    Dim responseTime As Integer = 0
    Dim answer As Boolean
    Dim startTime As Integer = DateTime.Now.Millisecond
    Dim endTime As Integer
    Dim socket As New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)

    Try
        With socket
            .ReceiveTimeout = time
            .Ttl = 64
            .SendTimeout = time
            .Connect(target, 21)
            .Dispose()
            .Close()
        End With
        endTime = DateTime.Now.Millisecond
        IIf(endTime - startTime < 0, responseTime = endTime + 1000, responseTime = endTime)
        answer = True

    Catch ex As Exception
        responseTime = time
        answer = False
    End Try

    Return {responseTime, answer}
End Function
```

When the FTP server is up and responsive , there is no problem, but when its not there, i hangs my app for ~15 seconds before it sends the exception.

The socket does not have timeout for the connection itself (only for send and receive commands - used in the function).

I have tried to wrap it with timer with no luck,
please help.

Guy

Answer (score 1):

Ok , After struggling with this thing for few hours, I found a solution for my problem

I actually used the System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient class

I have combined the asynchronous BeginConnect with a very simple While loop checking if connected, checking if the socket is connected

```
 Private Function TestFTP(ByVal target As String, ByVal time As Integer) As Object
    Dim responseTime As Integer = 0
    Dim answer As Boolean
    Dim startTime As Integer = DateTime.Now.Millisecond
    Dim endTime As Integer
    Dim t As TcpClient = New TcpClient(AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
    Dim loops As Integer
    time *= 2
    t.BeginConnect(target, 21, Nothing, t)
    While Not t.Connected
        Thread.Sleep(Int(time / 6))
        loops += 1
        If loops >= 6 Then Exit While
    End While
    endTime = DateTime.Now.Millisecond
    t.Close()
    If loops >= 6 Then
        answer = False
        responseTime = 300
    Else
        answer = True
        If endTime >= startTime Then
            responseTime = endTime - startTime
        Else
            responseTime = endTime - startTime + 1000
        End If
    End If


    Return {responseTime, answer}
End Function
```

That did the trick for me, hope it helps someone.